# Как обойти явное ожидание selenium, чтобы пропустить итерацию цикла

Tags: python, selenium, потоки-данных, распараллеливание

Как сделать так, чтобы вовремя того как мы ждем с помощью wait.until() я мог выполнить параллельно другой код, который мог бы пропустить итерацию цикла, в котором находится код wait.until().
Например:

```
def skip(text):
    if text == "скип":
        # Как можно вернуться в функцию show и пропустить ожидание, выполнив только 
        # watched.append(trailer) и пойти дальше в цикле for функции show?
def show():
    watched = []
    for trailer in trailers:
        driver.get(trailer)
        end_block = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ended-mode")))
        watched.append(trailer)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы когда я дохожу до строки end_block в функции show, чтобы можно было передать контроль функции skip и чтобы функция skip могла выполнить блок кода функции show после end_block. Как можно обойти явное ожидание на строке end_block?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732958/python-parallel-execution-with-selenium

Comment: спасибо, решил с помощью  concurrent.futures.